# How to create sessions for databases in pytest?

Tags: python, postgresql, automated-tests, pytest, pg8000

I have some pytest project where I do some postgresql requests. I have some functions like get_json, get_user, get_message to get some specific objects from databases and I use these funcs inside of my fixtures. These funcs looks kinda like this:

```
def get_expected_status_code_API01(role, incident_type="a"):
    connection = pg8000.connect(**constants.AUTOTESTS_DB_CREDS)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT status_code FROM pytest.api01_roles_and_status_codes WHERE role=%s AND incident_type=%s", [role, incident_type])
    status_code = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return status_code
```

So, yeah, I open and close connections in every query :( It was ok while I had not that much tests, but now I have an error "pg8000.dbapi.ProgrammingError: {'S': 'FATAL', 'V': 'FATAL', 'C': '53300', 'M': 'sorry, too many clients already', 'F': 'proc.c', 'L': '346', 'R': 'InitProcess'}".
I supposed it would be ok since I created and closed connections, but for some reason it didn't work this way.
I think I need some db sessions, but how exactly can I do that?

Comment: Move your connection into a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#back-to-fixtures), and then pass it around as necessary. So e.g., `get_expected_status_code_API01` would receive a database connection object as a parameter, rather than creating a new connection.

Comment: In addition to @larsks comment, I sugest you to use Mocks (unittest.mock) to emulate the database in your tests

Comment: Somehow those connections aren't being closed. In your debugging it might be helpful to run the SQL query "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;" which returns a row for each current connection. Also, maybe try for one test to see if even that closes the connection?